# Yielding from a factory generated by a pytest fixture

Tags: python, pytest, generator, factory, fixtures

The following pytest fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def gen_factory():
    def _gen_factory(owner: str):

        value = ...

        yield value

        print('gen teardown')

    yield _gen_factory
```

yields a factory used multiple times.

In a test case, I use that fixture to create two factory and use them to produce some values:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
def test_case(gen_factory):
    gen1 = gen_factory('owner1')
    gen2 = gen_factory('owner2')
    val1 = next(gen1)
    val2 = next(gen2)

    ...

    next(gen1)
    next(gen2)
```

What happens is that the `print('gen teardown')` is called only once and then the loop is closed and the second `next()` call raises a `StopIteration` error.

What am I missing here? Why is the second print not happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### If you don't want to change anything in the fixture, just change the last calls to `next`:

```
next(gen1, None)
```

With a default value it won't raise `StopIteration`.

##### An alternative is to make `_gen_factory` a context manager:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

def gen_factory():
    @contextmanager
    def _gen_factory(owner):
        value = owner
        yield value
        print('gen teardown')
    yield _gen_factory
    

def test_case(genfactory):   
    with genfactory('owner1') as own1, genfactory('owner2') as own2:
        print(own1, own2)
```

The error happens on the (last but one) line having the second call to `next(gen1)`, before it executes the last statement (`next(gen2)`). The iterator is exhausted. That's how generators work. **`StopIteration` is raised at the end of the generator, (That's why the first one is printed!)** once they have no items to be iterated over, unless a default value is passed to the builtin `next` function. `StopIteration` makes the for loop stop. Although generators can be used in different ways, their use is primarily to be iterated over in a for loop. That's why, by default, this 'exception' is raised.

See this [tutorial on generators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/generators-in-python).

Comment: why the second print is not happening? after the first generator tears down the event loop is closed and the second will remain pending

Comment: Because the error happens before it prints the second teardown on `next(gen1)`

Comment: Maybe I'm still not getting it but why after calling `next(gen1)` and `next(gen2)` nothing is printed? I was expecting both generators to be exhausted but debugging I see that the code after `yield value` is not executed

Comment: As I explained, `StopIteration` is raised. Try changing `next(gen1)` to `next(gen1, None)` only. You'll see the error will be in the line that has `next(gen2)`.  The last calls, as I explained have to be provided a default value. You have only ONE yield statement which is equivalent to one `next`. There are no items to be iterated anymore.

Comment: As I explained, use `next(gen1, None)` and `next(gen2, None)` on the last calls. There will be no errors.

Comment: `StopIteration` is raised at the end of the generator. That's why the first one is printed!

Comment: I get it that `StopIteration` is raised once `next(gen1)` is called again but I added the last two calls at the end of the test case because nothing is printed after the first two `next` calls

Comment: So, to be clear, if I remove the last two `next` call, after `val1 = next(gen1)` and `val2 = next(gen2)` are invoked, the test case ends and no `gen teardown` is printed

Comment: Exactly! That's why I suggested you to use a context manager. That's how generators work. Once you call `yield` the context goes to the function that called `next`. It will be resumed once called `next` again. The code after yield is executed, stoping at another `yield`. If there are no items left, `StopIteration` is raised.